# Python OSC installation using pip

Tags: pip, installation, osc

I am trying to install the **Python package OSC** using pip. It keeps showing up errors of:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement osc

I have pip 9.0.1. Do you know this error? How can I install OSC?

Thanks,
Miya

Comment: Were you able to install OSC?

Comment: Thank you Andrew, it work's with your answer.

Comment: Awesome glad I could help, feel free to use the checkmark to accept the answer for anyone who references this question in the future!

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you are trying to install Open Sound Control (OSC). Here is the Python package on PyPI: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-osc

To install: `pip install python-osc`